# unable to assign text[] value to variable in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, procedure

```
raise notice 'output %', arr[i]->>val;
data_ = arr[i]->>val::text[];
```

raise notice is giving proper output as

```
["cust_full_name","cust_email"]
```

but when 2nd line is giving error when executing

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: json ->> text[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

where data_ is type text[] and
arr[i]->>val => val is variable which is conaining dynamic key of object which is string.

i am trying to execute above statements in pgsql of procedural function.

i tried various inbuild methods of pgsql but none of them worked such as

```
data_ = jsonb_array_elements(arr[i]->>val);
```

```
data_ = jsonb_array_elements_text(arr[i]->>val);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to do `(arr[i]->>val)::text[]`, not `arr[i]->>(val::text[])`? But this wouldn't work either, if `arr[i]->>val` is the text representation of a JSON array, this won't be valid representation of a postgres text array - you'd still get a runtime exception because it cannot be parsed as a literal.

If `data_` should have type `json(b)`, then you should use `->` insted of `->>`:

```
data_ = arr[i] -> val;
```

If `data_` should have type `text[]`, then you'll need to create a postgres array from the string elements of the JSON array:

```
data_ = ARRAY(SELECT value FROM json_array_elements_text(arr[i] -> val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator `::` has higher priority than operator `->>`, so it is evaluated first, and next it should to fail, because `->>` operator expects string type on right side. Unfortunately, there is not any prepared cast from json to any array, so you should to use workaround like proposed @Bergi.